# Unable to delete data from multiple MySQL tables in one delete statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to delete data from multiple MySQL tables using following query;

```
$rel=$_POST['releaseno'];
$sql="DELETE from `tbl_uat`,`tbl_fault` WHERE `tbl_uat`.`release`='$rel' AND `tbl_fault`.`release_no`='$rel'";
```

I think there is a problem with the query, can any one please identify where's the problem.

Kind Regards

Comment: Seems like you didn't run mysqli_query for your sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the DB from which tables you want to delete by doing `delete u,f from ...`

```
$rel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['releaseno']);

DELETE u, f
from tbl_uat u, tbl_fault f
WHERE u.release = '$rel'
AND f.release_no = '$rel'
```

#### You also need to escape your user input before inserting into your query!

Comment: This is correct, but not the answer to the question; your code still does not execute a query.

Comment: @feeela: I added `u,f` to the first line which is the key.

Comment: uhm, sorry, I thought it should work without that too…